# NSRangeException when setting CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor of UIPageControl

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the color properties of a `UIPageControl` object from code. However it crashes. Settning the properties from Interface Builder works just fine.

The code:

```
float x = isLight ? 0.8f : 0.2f;
UIColor markedColor = UIColor.FromRGB (x, x, x);
pageControll.CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor = markedColor;
pageControll.PageIndicatorTintColor = isLight ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;
```

The error I get (on the third row):

`Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds for empty array`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem. Seems to be a bug in the SDK.

Since I had not yet received the data to "populate" the UIPageControl, the property `Pages` was set to 0. Changing this to 1 solved it.

```
float x = isLight ? 0.8f : 0.2f;
UIColor markedColor = UIColor.FromRGB (x, x, x);
if (pageControll.Pages < 1) {
    pageControll.Pages = 1;
}
pageControll.CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor = markedColor;
pageControll.PageIndicatorTintColor = isLight ? UIColor.White : UIColor.Black;
```

Comment: just lost so much time on this crap.  This is a bug!

Comment: Happens only on IOS 8. (as for my observations)